# Size of increments in commutative ring to reach given number

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

I have the ring $\Bbb Z_q = \{0,1,\ldots,q-1\}$, where $q$ is a prime.
Starting from $0$, I want to make exactly $n$ equally sized increments and reach $a\in \Bbb Z_q$, with $n<q-1$. For example if $q = 5$, and I want to reach $a=3$ with $n=4$ increments, I would use increments of $2$:

0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 -> 3

Is there a way to calculate the size of the increments that I need in O(1) time (i.e., without testing all possible answers)?

Comment: Let $k$ be the size of the increment you're looking for. Then this amounts to solving the congruence relation $kn \equiv a \pmod q$; for example, in your case, you are solving $4k \equiv 3 \pmod 5$, where $2$ is clearly a solution. Since $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ is always a field for $q$ prime, this amounts to finding the inverse of $n$ mod $q$, and then computing $k = n^{-1}a$. Computing the inverse of $n$ mod $q$ can be done using the Euclidean algorithm.